# OSX homebrew Lua51 cannot find lua command

Tags: lua, homebrew

When I install lua51 with brew, it is not able to run the command. However when I install just lua (homebrew install lua 5.2 by default) the lua command works.

I tried brew link but that shows lua51 already linked.

here is a transcript

```
$ brew install lua                                                                                        (master) 
Updating Homebrew...
....... Install output .......
  /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_4: 144 files, 705.5KB
$ lua                                                                                                     (master) 
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> 
$ brew uninstall lua                                                                                      (master) 
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_4... (144 files, 705.5KB)
$ lua                                                                                                     (master) 
zsh: command not found: lua
$ brew install lua51                                                                                      (master) 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/lua@5.1-5.1.5_4.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
....... Install output .......
  /usr/local/Cellar/lua@5.1/5.1.5_4: 136 files, 702.2KB
$ lua                                                                                                     (master) 
zsh: command not found: lua
```

Comment: Perhaps the program is called `lua51` instead of plain `lua`?

Comment: I tried lua51 too. No affect

Comment: looks like I needed the .

Comment: Normally, **homebrew** creates symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` so you just need to put that in your PATH. Then when you upgrade versions, it relinks to the newest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded `https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/lua@5.1-5.1.5_4.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz` and saw that it contains

```
./5.1.5_4/bin/lua-5.1
./5.1.5_4/bin/lua5.1 -> lua-5.1
```

So, you need to run `lua-5.1` or `lua5.1`, not plain `lua`.

Comment: That worked!! Having the 5.1 isnt too intuitive... Thanks